# Get the dependency tree of a maven project with a missing dependency

Tags: maven, dependencies, maven-3

First of all, let me start by saying `mvn dependency:tree` does not work in my scenario.
I'm working on an already existing codebase which is giving a build failure. The issue was that the maven repos (including nexus) does not have a POM for a transitive dependency (org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:pom:1.5.2) in this project.

I want to find where this dependency came from. It's probably a transitive dependency, because it isn't listed in the project's pom nor in parent poms. Invoking `mvn dependency:tree` does not work because it also fails with the same error I get when I use `mvn install` (Connection timeout). The error is given below.

So, how can I identify which dependency tries to download this pom? I'd like a general answer to find the dependency tree rather than focusing on wss4j pom stated above.

```
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sample/XKMS 4.5.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
Downloading: http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2/org/apache/ws/security/wss4j/1.5.2/wss4j-1.5.2.pom

[WARNING] The POM for bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk13:jar:132 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 3:10.155s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Mar 14 10:35:20 IST 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 7M/490M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project wso2appserver-samples-xkms: Could not resolve dependencies 
for project org.wso2.appserver:wso2appserver-samples-xkms:jar:4.5.0-SNAPSHOT: Failed to collect dependencies for [org.wso2.xkms:xkms:jar:2.2 (compile)]: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:jar:1.5.2: 
Could not transfer artifact org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:pom:1.5.2 from/to ws-zones-repository (http://ws.zones.apache.org/repository2): Error transferring file: Connection timed out -> [Help 1]
```

Comment: `[WARNING] The POM for bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk13:jar:132 is invalid, transitive dependencies (if any) will not be available, enable debug logging for more details` Add your pom - maybe one of the plugin (cxf) needed it

Comment: Are you saying that this warning is the reason for build failure? As I've seen so far, WARNINGs doesn't cause build failures. And, the error message says that "Could not transfer artifact org.apache.ws.security:wss4j:pom:1.5.2"!! What am I missing here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

```
mvn dependency:tree --debug
```

outputs the tree before failing in my case.

Comment: This is way better than installing some crazy eclipse plugin.  Worked for me.

Comment: Yes, this is working most of the time... In cases, I didn't see the tree though. But this is good enough. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

One way to find this out, is to install the m2eclipse Maven plugin for Eclipse. (If you have and are using Eclipse, that is.) The name is unrelated to the version; it works happily with at least Maven 2.2.1 and 3.

http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/

Then, open your root pom in Eclipse, and click on the `Dependency Hierarchy` tab. On the right-hand side will be all the dependencies the project will download, and on the left is what dependencies ask for what. If a dependency says `(managed from X)`, it means another dependency wants a different version of this dependency This isn't flawless, however. I still had too look at some of the other poms to find the dependency I was looking for. But it should make life easier, and at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: This is extra load of work. So, I couldn't quite go there to get my dependency tree listed up. Manually going through dependency pom to pom seems to be easier if you think the solution could be found at shallow water.